# How to split series of string by multi symbol?

Tags: python, pandas, string, split

At first, I have to write function GetTitle() method, where takes string, and this function must split the name till comma, then again split till dot, next convert the title to lower case and finally return this value of the title.

I wrote function, but I don't get how to use or rewrite this function for series of string

```
def GetTitle(Name):
    k=Name.split(" ")
    item=k[1]
    title=item.split(".")
    res=title[0]
    lower_res=res.lower()
    return lower_res
```

This my column, where I should use this function

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFzXC.png)

Comment: Using a regular expression may be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you wish to run your defined function on column "Name" & your data is loaded as df... Try this then;

```
df["Title"] = df["Name"].apply(lambda x: GetTitle(str(x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with a regex expression :

```
df['Title1'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r',\s(\w+).', expand=False)
```

Add [**`pandas.Series.str.lower`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) if you need to lowercase the title :

```
df['Title2'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r',\s(\w+).', expand=False).str.lower()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(df)

     Passengerld  Survived  Pclass                                             Name     Sex   Age  SibSp  Parch            Ticket     Fare Cabin Embarked Title1 Title2
0              1         0     NaN                          Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    male  22.0      1      0         A/5 21171   7.2500   NaN        S     Mr     mr
1              2         1     NaN  Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Th.  female  38.0      1      0          PC 17599  71.2833   C85        C    Mrs    mrs
2              3         1     NaN                           Heikkinen, Miss. Laina  female  26.0      0      0  STON/O2. 3101282   7.9250   NaN        S   Miss   miss
3              4         1     NaN     Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)  female  35.0      1      0            113803  53.1000  C123        S    Mrs    mrs
4              5         0     3.0                         Allen, Mr. William Henry    male  35.0      0      0            373450   8.0500   NaN        S     Mr     mr
886          887         0     2.0                            Montvila, Rev. Juozas    male  27.0      0      0            211536  13.0000   NaN        S    Rev    rev
887          888         1     1.0                     Graham, Miss. Margaret Edith  female  19.0      0      0            112053  30.0000   B42        S   Miss   miss
888          889         0     3.0         Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen "Carrie"   emale   NaN      1      2         W./C.6607  23.4500   NaN        S   Miss   miss
889          890         1     1.0                            Behr, Mr. Karl Howell    male  26.0      0      0            111369  30.0000  C148        C     Mr     mr
890          891         0     3.0                              Dooley, Mr. Patrick    male  32.0      0      0            370376   7.7500   NaN        Q     Mr     mr
```

Comment: Much better approach than the chosen one

Comment: Learning from you, _"Avoid loops and vectorize as much as you can"_ ;).

Comment: @abokey: I was just looking at this set again for diff purposes, and I noticed there is one particularly nasty entry that doesn't confirm to the assumed rule: `df.loc[759, 'Name']`, i.e. `'Rothes, the Countess. of (Lucy Noel Martha Dyer-Edwards)'`. Your regex will capture `'the'`. I managed to capture it as follows, though I imagine that a nicer pattern should be possible: `df['Name'].str.extract(r',\s([^.]*)(?=\.\s[A-Z\(])|,\s(.*)\s\(').fillna(axis=1, method='bfill')[0].str.lower().unique()`. Nobility... they always need to do things slightly differently, don't they...

Comment: @ouroboros1, thanks for pointing this out. I think something like `df['Tilte'] = df['Name'].str.extract(r',\s(\w+\s?\w*).', expand=False)` should do the job.

Comment: @abokey: almost, that will get us `'the Countess'`, rather than `'the Countess. of'`. So, the annoying thing is that the "title" uniquely continues after the dot. I was at any rate also trying to capture the last bit. Otherwise, I could imagine that the OP might be interested in just `'Countess'`, so also without `'the'`. That wouldn't be too difficult of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) for this with alternative delimiters:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Bar, Mr. Foo',
                            'Baz, Miss. Bar']})

df['Title'] = df.Name.str.split('. |, ', expand=True)[1].str.lower()

print(df)

             Name Title
0    Bar, Mr. Foo    mr
1  Baz, Miss. Bar  miss
```